# Difficulties with orthogonal density estimation

Tags: nonparametric, density-estimation, basis-function

I am working on an implementation of an orthogonal density estimator, using the basis

$$ \psi_0(t) = 1, \quad \psi_{2j}(t) = \sqrt{2}\text{cos}(2\pi j t), \quad \psi_{2j+1}(t) = \sqrt{2}\text{sin}(2\pi j t)$$

so that for a sample $X = \{X_0,X_1,...,X_n\} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ from a density $f$ we have the following estimate

$$\hat{f}(t) = \sum_{i=0}^k \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{n} \psi_j(X_j) \psi_i(t)$$

As straightforward as this seems, I am having difficulties in obtaining any useful estimates; the function $f(t)$ seems to not converge no matter what function/density I am trying to estimate. As an example, trying to estimate samples from a standard exponential distribution, i.e $f(t) = e^{-t}$ for $t \in [0,1]$, using $k = 10$ terms in the approximation the resulting estimate is

[image]

which is typical, for most functions I attempt to estimate the result is simply oscillations, with the number/intensity oscillations increasing with $k$. **Does anyone know that the problem might be, or can recommend datasets with accompanying analysis to help diagnose the problem?** I have attached the code for the estimation procedure (in Scala) below:

```
// Evaluate basis functions
def phi(t: Double, j: Integer): Double = {
    var p = 1.0
    if(j != 0){ 
      p = math.sqrt(2)*(math.cos((2*math.Pi*j)*t)*((j+1)%2) + math.sin((2*math.Pi*j)*t)*(j%2))
    }
  return(p)
}

// Compute the coefficients 
def coeff(x: Array[Double], j: Integer): Double = {
  var sum = 0.0
  var theta_j = 0.0
  val n = x.length
  for(i <- 0 to n-1){
    sum = sum + phi(x(i),j)
  }
  theta_j = sum*(1/n.toDouble)
  return(theta_j)
}

// Obtaining the estimate of f at the poing t, using k terms 
def f_hat(t: Double, x: Array[Double], k: Integer): Double = {
  var ft = 0.0
  val n = x.length.toDouble
  for(j <- 0 to k){
    ft = ft + coeff(x, j)*phi(t, j)
  }
  return(ft)
}
```